# Removing default validation messages from intbox in ZKOSS

Tags: validation, input, zk

If I enter i.e. "0000000" into `<intbox>`, some default validator shows an error tooltip saying "You must specify an integer, rather than 0000000". I want to get rid of that message completely and just change value of input to "0". Any help would be great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by overriding widgets default `showError_` method, thats where error messages are created... it now looks like

```
zk.$package("foo").MyIntbox = zk.$extends(zul.inp.Intbox, {
    $init: function() {   
        this.$super('$init', arguments);
        // some custom logic
    },
    showError_ : function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `org.zkoss.zul.Intbox#coerceFromString` in you custom subclass `IntboxCustomSubclass` (name used in this example) and then add it as custom component to `lang.xml` in you application. For custom components see at http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Language_Definition.

```
<component>
  <component-name>intbox</component-name>
  <component-class>org.zkoss.zul.IntboxCustomSubclass</component-class>
  <widget-class>zul.inp.Intbox</widget-class>
  <mold>
    <mold-name>default</mold-name>
    <mold-uri>mold/input.js</mold-uri>
    <css-uri>css/input.css.dsp</css-uri>
  </mold>
  <mold>
    <mold-name>rounded</mold-name>
    <mold-uri>mold/input.js</mold-uri>
    <css-uri>css/input.css.dsp</css-uri>
  </mold>
</component>
```

Put here your test for a string with value like '0000000' and return 0 back:

```
// here.
try {
  int v = Integer.parseInt(val);
  int divscale = vals[1] != null ? ((Integer)vals[1]).intValue(): 0;
  while (v != 0 && --divscale >= 0)
    v /= 10;
  return new Integer(v);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  throw showCustomError(
    new WrongValueException(this, MZul.NUMBER_REQUIRED, value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried what you suggested but it had no influence on that validation... i ended up with customizing widgets doKeyPress_ event and I am checking users input there in js on client...

Comment: Can you post an example of what you did - I mean when you tried to change default validation in Java code?

Comment: I just made `public class MyIntbox extends org.zkoss.zul.Intbox` with overriden method `coerceFromString` and then I used that class with `use` parameter of `intbox`.  It seems to me that `coerceFromString` method has nothing to do with validation I was talking about...

Comment: Ok, I finally got a solution - the method I was looking for is `zul.inp.Intbox#coerceFromString_` which is js function on widget that shows that validation I mentioned in my question... I just wrote my own implementation of Intbox widget and everything is ok. Anyway thanks for pointing me to that function, I only had to realize that I need to override its js client version.

Comment: Hmm, even better now, if I override widgets `showError_` method I can control style of all error messages of that widget(I am just printing them to js console now because we use different system for displaying validation errors). Just in case you are interested... ;-)

Comment: I want to control Validation Popup. Instead of just getting popup open I would like to see the error popup when I click or focus on component. Do you have some approach????

Comment: @Gatekeeper: Can you provide your code so that I can understand how can we handle default messages. I am facing these problems with datebox,intbox etc.

Comment: @psisodia I am sorry but I am not working on that project any longer so I cannot provide you any actual code. There are some objects storing default widget messaget that can be overriden, if you want to change behaviour of widgets like I needed you will have to override some of its functions or write your own implementation. There is some documentation about how to do it but its not easy to find. Anyway ZKOSS support was very quick and helpfull in cases like this, I would suggest asking them if you have contract on support they will point you to the right direction.

Comment: @Gatekeeper: I have tried what you are saying.I have created customized Intbox as CustomIntbox.java and put entry of this class in lang-addon.xml. Use this class in my xul page using use keyword. But this way is not working for me

Comment: @psisodia well you have to decide if you want to change component java implementation or you want to change behaviour of its javascript widget object(like in my asnwer below). Messages i wanted to get rid of were displayed by js widget on client not java. See this link http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/General_Control/Widget_Customization

Comment: Same thing I want to do.I have to override the javascript of Intbox

Comment: I need to change the behaviour of intbox without using zcript

Comment: @psisodia well then do it :-) look here for complete Intbox source and then just override any method you want like in my answer https://code.google.com/p/zklighter/source/browse/trunk/zul/src/archive/web/js/zul/inp/Intbox.js?r=2